# Using unicode in CSVRecordSetWriter escape character

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

Is is possible to use a unicode character in `CSVRecordSetWriter` controller service Escape Character? I used '\u0003' as delimiter and it didn't throw any error but on using '\u0004' as Escape Character, it throws error.

**Update**

On the same lines, `CSVReader` controller service doesn't have `Record Separator` property. Meaning if I write a csv with the row separator anything other than '\n', I will not be able to read it from NiFi. :|

Comment: You could use ReplaceText to replace your record separator with "\n", then you can should be able to use CSVReader.